# Program finds the max and min correctly at first run, but if I run it again, it would give me wrong answer

Tags: c++

I can not figure out where the problem is: When I run the program first time, everything is ok but after that always wrong answer. I am guessing it maybe some kind of memory leak, but I can not figure it out.

```
//user has already defined ArraySize;

int *pRnd= new signed int[ArraySize];

int *pMin; 

int *pMax;

pMin = &pRnd[0];

pMax = &pRnd[0];

//pRnd is already filled with random numbers.

for (int *counter = pRnd; counter < (pRnd + ArraySize); counter++){

    if (counter != (pRnd + (ArraySize-1)))
    {

        if (*counter> *(counter + 1))
            pMaxElementValue = counter;

        if (*counter < *(counter + 1))
            pMinElementValue = counter;
    }

}


cout << setw(5) << "Max array element:" << setw(20) << *pMax << endl;
cout << setw(5) << "Min array element:" << setw(20) << *pMin << endl;

delete []pRnd; // clear the memory
```

Comment: First, no need for `new` and `delete`; use a `std::vector` or something. Second, no need to reinvent the wheel; use `std::minmax_element`.

Comment: You need to be comparing against your min and max variables not against the next value in the array.

Comment: Thank you for your repond  Chris, well, I would write it differently, if I was allowed but this is an assignment and I have to create dynamic array, use pointer to loop (not allowed to index) and at the end of the run my pointers should point to max and min.

Comment: @john: It is almost always wrong to use a dynamic array like this. Whoever gave you this assignment teaches a very questionable kind of C++, unless the purpose is to teach you the horrors and uselessness of manual memory management with `new[]` and `delete[]` :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl I think you're overstating the case here, there's plenty of valid reasons to use `new[]`

Comment: @Alnitak: Such as? I cannot think of any reason not to use `std::vector`, `std::array` or, in a few cases, static raw arrays. `new[]` is pretty much a broken feature of C++ (it's not even used inside `std::vector` implementations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic used to track the max and min values is not right.

```
    if (*counter> *(counter + 1))
```

doesn't tell you whether `*counter` is greater than the previous max value. Same problem with the line

```
    if (*counter< *(counter + 1))
```

It doesn't tell you whether `*counter` is less than the previous min value.

Assuming `pMaxElementValue` and `pMinElementValue` are values, not pointers, the core logic can be simplified to:

```
pMaxElementValue = *pRnd;
pMinElementValue = *pRnd;

for (int *counter = pRnd; counter < (pRnd + ArraySize); counter++)
{
   if (*counter> pMaxElementValue )
      pMaxElementValue = *counter;

   if (*counter < pMinElementValue)
      pMinElementValue = *counter;
}
```

If you want to use pointers for the elements containing max and min, you need to use:

```
pMax = pRnd;
pMin = pRnd;

for (int *counter = pRnd; counter < (pRnd + ArraySize); counter++)
{
   if (*counter> *pMax )
      pMax = counter;

   if (*counter < *pMin)
      pMin = counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are wrong (all three of them), you should compare value pointed by `counter` (pretty bad name btw) to max and min:

```
for (int *counter = pRnd + 1; counter < (pRnd + ArraySize); counter++) {

    if (*counter> *pMax )
        pMax = counter;

    if (*counter < *pMin )
        pMin = counter;
 }
```

You can still have int `counter = pRnd` but you will do one additional comparison that is not necessary, as `pMax` and `pMin` already point to the first element.

Comment: two separate answers?

Comment: @Alnitak has issue with internet, that was not intentional